# Two databases in Grails

Tags: grails

I want to work with 2 database in grails project,how can i defined 2 databases and how the domain Class and controller class point to the correct database ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you access two databases in Grails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41018/how-do-you-access-two-databases-in-grails)

Answer (score 3):

There is  Grails plugin that enables the use of multiple datasources directly with Grails' GORM layer: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=70

But as of grails 2.0 you can do it natively. http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#multipleDatasources