# How to use MySQL and MSSQL together in the grails datasource?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, grails

I have an grails application that uses MySQL for authentication purpose and another application that uses MSSQL for database stuff. I need to combine these together as one application. The datasource for MySQL contains the following

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}
```

The datasource for application using MSSQL contains the following

```
dataSource {

    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" //jdbc driver downloaded from internet: sqljdbc4.jar and sqljdbc_auth.dll (see DisplayHistorical/grails-app/lib)
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect"

    ClassName = "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" //Original Code
// enable loggingSql to see sql statements in stdout 
    loggingSql = true

}
```

How would I combine these? I looked at the tutorial mentioned on this site ([How do you access two databases in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41018/how-do-you-access-two-databases-in-grails)) but it doesnt talk about adding the drivers

Comment: You should have a look at [multiple datasource capability in grails](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources) before looking anything else.

Comment: thanks will have a look there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the [link](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources) provided earlier, then you would end up with a datasource configuration like below:

```
environments {
    production {
        dataSource_authentication {
            pooled = true
            url = "jdbc:mysql://yourServer/yourDB"
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            username = "yourUser"
            password = "yourPassword"
            ........
        }
        dataSource {
            pooled = true
            driverClassName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
            dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect"
            ........
        }
    }
}
```

Where ever required you can use the `authentication` datasource explicitly.